# Swagger not working with Django BaseSerializer object

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm using **django-rest-swagger** to document and test an API and it has been working very well up to now but the following error has occured:

***AttributeError at /docs/api-docs/app
'PeriodSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_fields'***

'PeriodSerializer' inherits from serializers.BaseSerializer:

```
class PeriodSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {
            'lower': instance.lower,
            'upper': instance.upper
        }

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = json.loads(data)

        date_lower = self.date_from_str(data["lower"])
        date_upper = self.date_from_str(data["upper"])

        # some code omitted for brevity

        return DateTimeTZRange(lower=date_lower, upper=date_upper)


    @staticmethod
    def date_from_str(datestr):
        # code omitted for brevity
```

The code itself works fine, it's just that django-rest-swagger appears to have a problem with it. I'm using:

- Python   3.4.0
- Django   1.8.2
- DRF  3.1.3
- django-rest-swagger  0.3.2

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Django Rest Framework's `BaseSerializer` doesn't have a `get_fields` function. You can see that in that in the [source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L58).

Short answer: Use `Serializer`, not `BaseSerializer`. Your code will work the same, and you won't have to worry about it. If for some reason you need to use `BaseSerializer` and `django-rest-swagger` together, you'll have to implement `get_fields` yourself.

If you look at the implementation of get_fields in a higher-level serializer (like `Serializer`) you'll see get_fields is defined like so:

```
def get_fields(self):
    """
    Returns a dictionary of {field_name: field_instance}.
    """
    # Every new serializer is created with a clone of the field instances.
    # This allows users to dynamically modify the fields on a serializer
    # instance without affecting every other serializer class.
    return copy.deepcopy(self._declared_fields)
```

Using BaseSerializer, you won't have access to self._declared_fields either. You can see how that works in the linked source above, but the gist of it is that it returns a dictionary of attributes of the Field type.

> Any instances of `Field` included as attributes on either the class
>       or on any of its superclasses will be include in the
>       `_declared_fields` dictionary.

I hope this helps answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

Though late to the party but what works for me is something like this:

```
@six.add_metaclass(serializers.SerializerMetaclass)
class PeriodSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):

    def get_fields(self):
        """
        Returns a dictionary of {field_name: field_instance}.
        """
        # Every new serializer is created with a clone of the field instances.
        # This allows users to dynamically modify the fields on a serializer
        # instance without affecting every other serializer class.
        return copy.deepcopy(self._declared_fields)
```

i.e you need to decorate the class with a meta class which provides for _declared_field and then you can implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try out [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#example-project). It is another swagger generator with support for the newer versions of Django Rest Framework.